# Re-arrange columns within R dataframe matching with column name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

In an R dataframe named 'df,' we have multiple columns with similar names, distinguished only by the suffix '_CA_NAME.' For example, there might be columns like "List of product" and "List of product _CA_NAME." The objective is to rearrange the dataframe so that each column with '_CA_NAME' is placed immediately after its corresponding column without '_CA_NAME,' without altering the overall structure of the dataframe.

The result should be a modified 'df' dataframe where columns with '_CA_NAME' are positioned directly after their counterparts without '_CA_NAME,' without changing the structure of the dataframe.

Note - The column nubmer after removing suffix is exact same.

Comment: Provide example data, `x <- colnames(mydata)` or `dput(head(mydata))`